# ocp-build.conf syntax for multiple worker processes?

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocp-build

I'd like to configure my OCaml OPAM builds to run multiple worker processes in parallel.  There's actually a ticket on the OPAM github for this

https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam/issues/310

which says I just need to write an ocp-build.conf file.  Unfortunately, I have been completely unsuccessful in finding any documentation on the syntax of this config file.  I have S'edTFW and would be delighted to RTFM if only I could find it.

Does anyone happen to know how to configure ocp-build for multiple worker processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time `ocp-build` is called, it creates both a global file `~/.ocp/ocp-build.conf` (`~` is your home directory) and a local file `ocp-build.root` in the project.

Depending on your version of `ocp-build`, both files define an option `ncores` (older versions) or `njobs` (recent versions). In `ocp-build.root`, the default value is `None`, meaning that the value is not set, and the default should be used (i.e. the value from the global file).

For example, in my `~/.ocp/ocp-build.conf` file, I have `ncores = 5` (and `njobs = 5`, as I use also the most recent version), which means that 5 processes can be started in parallel (I use a quad-core, so anything > 4 is good).

Note that `ocp-build` can only parallelize compilation if dependencies are not too strong, or you compile both in bytecode and native code at the same time.